# IE 8 overflow/ellipsis

Tags: internet-explorer, text, internet-explorer-8, overflow, ellipsis

So I'm working to get the ellipsis class working on some pages (here's a page that explains the basic fix: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/ellipsis-html-css/), and it's working for IE 6 and 7, but not for IE 8. Here's the code:

```
.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    _width: 100%;
}
```

All that's happening is the text wraps like usual. Any suggestions?